# PHP DOM - counting child nodes?

Tags: php, dom

**HTML snippet #1**

```
<div>
</div>
<div>
    <h1>headline</h1>
</div>
```

**HTML snippet #2**

```
<div></div>
<div><h1>headline</h1></div>
```

**PHP code**

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($x);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$divs = $xpath->query("//div");

foreach ($divs as $div) echo $div->childNodes->length,"<br />";
```

**Output with `$x =` snippet #1**
    1
    3

**Output with `$x =` snippet #2**
    0
    1

see working demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/11BGge

**My questions**
  1. How can this be?
  2. How to count child nodes correctly with `DOM`?

**EDIT**:
as Silkfire said, empty space is considered a text node. I set

```
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
```

but the results are still the same: http://codepad.viper-7.com/bnG5io

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a forum type question. SO is not a forum, you are not new here, you should know...

Comment: @DainisAbols: from the FAQ: (...) if your question generally covers a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, software tools commonly used by programmers, practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession - then you’re in the right place to ask your question! In this sense my question qualifies. Take that down vote back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just count non-text nodes in your loop:

```
$count = 0;
foreach($div->childNodes as $node)    
  if(!($node instanceof \DomText))      
    $count++;

print $count;
```

---

Using xpath:

```
$nodesFromDiv1 = $xpath->query("//div[1]/*")->length;
$nodesFromDiv2 = $xpath->query("//div[2]/*")->length;
```

---

To remove empty text nodes, when `preserveWhiteSpace=false` is not working (as I suggested in the chat):

```
$textNodes = $xpath->query('//text()');

foreach($textNodes as $node)
  if(trim($node->wholeText) === '')
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
```

Comment: nice workaround! But is there a way to remove all whitespace?

Comment: setting `preserveWhiteSpace` to false should do that, but it appears it's not always reliable

Comment: Is the HTML valid? Note that you must put that line before `->loadHTML`

Comment: the HTML is as in my question. I have `preserveWhitespace = false` before `loadHTML`, doesn't work though. I like that xpath-workaround.

Comment: If you're running on windows, perhaps it's related [to this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=31873)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29694/discussion-between-michi-and-one-trick-pony)

Comment: This isn't recursive

Answer (score 4):

Whitespace is considered a node because it is a *text()* node (`DOMText`).

You can make this work by changing your `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($divs as $div) {
    echo $div->childNodes->length - $xpath->query('./text()', $div)->length, '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firefox,Chrome and most other browsers, will treat empty white-spaces or new lines as text nodes, Internet Explorer will not.Check 
[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_element_childnodes.asp)

Comment: interesting, I wasn't aware oft that. Until one hour ago, I thought whitespace was just whitespace...