# Check for empty element

Tags: php, xpath, xml-parsing, simplexml

For this XML:

```
<row>
   <entry XY="1" al="23" se="5" ag="fgh"> </entry>
   <entry XY="1" al="23" se="5" ag="fgh">Content1</entry>
   <entry XY="1" al="23" se="5" ag="fgh">Content2</entry>
   <entry XY="1" al="23" se="5" ag="fgh"> </entry>
   <entry XY="1" al="23" se="5" ag="fgh">Content3</entry>
</row>
```

I have the following loop:

```
foreach ($toc_element->entry as $toc_element_line) {

  if ($toc_element_line->xpath('/*[text()]')) {

       array_push($arr, $toc_element_line); 

  }

}
```

I am trying to test if the current element is empty. The Object itself is never empty, because the potentially empty element, always has attributes (that I don't care about).

Is the XPath approach (which I am noticeably new to) correct? If so, how would I write it?

Thanks a lot in advance. (I know that there are some questions of that kind here on stackoverflow, but I couldn't quite figure it out)

Comment: you might want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471073/php-dom-counting-child-nodes

Comment: You don't give any XML example so I'm not so sure, but maybe http://php.net/strlen is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, your XPath looks good. It will return the element just for the case where there is text as a child node present.

Comment: I added an XML Snippet to better explain the situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<entry> </entry>` is NOT empty, it contains `' '`

in contrast to `<entry></entry>` or `<entry />` which is empty.

So, taken your XML example, use `xpath` to create an array of nodes NOT empty and NOT `' '`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$nodes = $xml->xpath("//entry[text() and text()!=' ']");
foreach ($nodes as $node) echo "$node<br />"; // output
```

See it working: http://3v4l.org/8Y7uN